# SQL List of products not included in any transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Transactions_Products(tref,prod_id) and Products(prod_id,prod_name,price).
How to find product_id of Products which is not in any of Transactions_Products.

I have tried using NOT IN but it didn't work as expected

Comment: Post your query, not a description of it.

Comment: If `not in` (which is the most obvious solution for this) "doesn't work as expected", how should we know that any other solution will "work as expected" without sample data, your current query and your "expectations" about results?

Answer (score 1):

I would use exists here:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Transactions_Products tp
    WHERE tp.prod_id = p.prod_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could beside the option `NOT EXISTS` (see Tim's answer) also use a `LEFT JOIN` and select the products which can't be found in the transactions table (which means Transactions_Products.prod_id is null):

```
SELECT p.prod_id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN Transactions_Products tp 
ON p.prod_id = tp.prod_id     
WHERE tp.prod_id IS NULL;
```

This query will likely be slower than `NOT EXISTS` when the tables have millions of rows (there have been analysis that prove this), otherwise, it shouldn't make a noticeable difference.

Many people prefer using `JOIN` for such purposes because they think it's more readable. But this is of course kind of taste.

So I advice you to choose the option you like more, unless the size of your table requires the fastest query, in this case `NOT EXISTS` should always be prefered.